# Firefox dropping style selectors involving :before and :after

Tags: css, firefox, less, pseudo-element

I work on a project where we quite often have LESS looking kind of like this:

```
.boxed,
.boxed-band,
.boxed-band:before,
.boxed-band:after,
.boxed-image {
  background-color: green;

  &.section{
    // Adds padding for all children except the headline.
    h2 {
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently if you throw the resulting compiled code at Firefox it simply gives up and chooses not to interpret the rule at all. All other major browsers seems to have no issues understanding what is going on. If you don't believe me, check this pen:

http://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/wKPLRL?editors=110

We have experienced the problem many times and it seems the only consistent solution is to do something like this:

```
.boxed,
.boxed-band,
.boxed-image {
  // Some rules.
}

.boxed-band:before,
.boxed-band:after {
  // Same rules as above ...duplicated... yuck!...
}
```

Have anyone else experienced something like this and have you found solutions that does not involve replicating CSS properties over and over?

Comment: What's the problem? I use firefox and I don't see nothing weird in the codepen. You are writing background color green in all elements, so what's the difference?

Comment: Look at your compilied CSS, it is wrong.

Comment: I have no idea why FF would reject this except that it's probably doing it right and the others aren't. The compiled CSS implies that pseudo-elements can have classes and sub-elements...which they can't. See `.boxed-band:before.section h2,`

Comment: I see now, @Paulie_D you're right. So is not a firefox problem, that browser is the only one that makes fine the standards. If the other are buggie, don't make guilty firefox xDDD

Comment: I was in another problems like this, that people tell that firefox have a bug, and finally the bug is in the other browsers hahaha

Comment: Apparently Firefox does not tolerate bugs :)

Comment: The other browsers will sorta 'round up' and firefox doesn't. I like it - because I can check in FF to ensure there are no bugs. - But yeah, it's not FF – it's the code.

Comment: Right. That's a very good point that pseudo-elements cannot have classes themselfes. Maybe this is something that should be guarded in the LESS-linter? Does anyone know if this is possible? I just want to make sure that we don't keep repeating this error and unfortunately I don't think we are going to get +20 developers to run FF instead of whatever their favourite browser might be.

Comment: That's just how it is; different browsers respond differently to errors. There will also be situations where Firefox manages to render something just the way you wanted and Chrome gives up in frustration. Or how about this: `<hr color="red" style="color:cyan">`  Which browser does it the right way? Answer: there is no right way!